# ansible hosts file - group_names issue

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

following is the content of my "hosts" file. how to print which groups "web_svr1" is part of? it should print all_servers and web_servers.

```
[web_servers]
web_svr1
web_svr2

[app_servers]
app_svr1

[all_servers:children]
web_servers
app_servers
```

I tried below code to print group names but it doesn't work.

```
  - name: Debug task to print group names
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: "Host belongs to group:"
    loop: "{{ group_names }}"
```

Comment: => `msg: "Host belongs to group: {{ item }}"`

Answer (score -1):

i figured it out, {{ item }} will iterate through group_names

```
msg: "Host belongs to group: {{ item }}"
```

group_names[0] will be all_servers
group_names[1] will be web_servers